# How to import images dynamically for avada image carousel from one wordpress site to another using api?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am having two WordPress site with two different MySQL DB's running in my localhost development system, I am using Avada theme, in the second site I am using image carousel, If I upload images in my first site, then the image carousel in my second site should take the images from my first site by using API. Since I am new to Wordpress and PHP I don't have an idea. can anybody help me solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We are happy to help you with specific questions, but this is too broad.

Comment: @GJNilsen I want to add images from my another wp site into avada carousel! i dont have any idea how to do it?